# c# - How could I refactor this switch statement to use minimum number code lines?

Tags: c#

```
switch (userSelection)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List1");
        listTitle = "List1 Title";
        validAnswer = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List2");
        listTitle = "List2 Title";
        validAnswer = true;
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List3");
        listTitle = "List3 Title";
        validAnswer = true;
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List4");
        listTitle = "List4 Title";
        validAnswer = true;
        break;
        default:
        Console.WriteLine(" Your selection is invalid. Please 
        try again.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Look at what's common - pull it into a function.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to switch at all given that the action is the same each time. Just an `if` to check the input is 1-4 and then you can use string interpolation to create the list name.

Comment: Why do you use a `switch` at all: `if (userSelection < 1 || userSelection > 4) Console.WriteLine(" Your selection is invalid. Please try again."); else { validAnswer = true; listTitle = $"List{userSelection} Title"; Console.WriteLine($" You selected: List{userSelection}"); }`

Comment: sounds like codegolf

Comment: Thanks for the answers, those title are just as examples. What I really want is to separate them from the "if" so that they could be changed without affecting the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that your title is really not `List1 Title` but something more realistic, you can store those titles in `Dictionary` object:

```
Dictionary<int, string> titles = new Dictionary<int,string>();
titles.Add(1, "List1 Title"); //Any title here
titles.Add(2, "List2 Title"); //Any title here
titles.Add(3, "List3 Title"); //Any title here
titles.Add(4, "List4 Title"); //Any title here

if (userSelection > 0 && userSelection < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List" + userSelection);
    listTitle = titles[userSelection];
    validAnswer = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(" Your selection is invalid. Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: thank you. Yes, the correct approach would be not to depend on those titles.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `if` / `else`

```
if (userSelection > 0 && userSelection < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" You selected: List" + userSelection);
    listTitle = "List" + userSelection + " Title";
    validAnswer = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(" Your selection is invalid. Please try again.");
}
```

---

If it's really just about the minimum number code lines...

```
validAnswer = userSelection > 0 && userSelection < 5;
Console.WriteLine(validAnswer ? " You selected: List" + userSelection : " Your selection is invalid. Please try again.");
if (validAnswer) listTitle = "List" + userSelection + " Title";
```